# Single record of model in database

Tags: django

My django app needs to display data on my homepage which it collected from third party. Requesting the information and waiting for response takes about a second, which is too long processing time for a homepage. The data which my app receives doesn't change often, so there is no reason to fetch that data every time homepage is being rendered. Instead, I want to retain the data and have my app make a request only if the last "refresh" has been done more than an hour ago.

Since using global variables in django is apparently a no-no, I'd need to make a database model which will at all times hold a single record. This feels wrong. Is making a one-record table really a way to go here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a model to cache the remote site's response, you can use Django's caching framework. More specifically, you can cache a specific view and set a timeout for the cached view. See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache) documentation page for more details on how to do that.

Comment: Note that you can also just cache the third-parts data - not necessarily the whole view - if you need these data elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, low-level caching is perfect for storing data received from third party.